# How do I connect my laptop(mobile hotspot) and my desktop(mobile USB tethering)? Can I do a LAN without ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, lan, wifi-configuration

How do I connect my laptop (which is using the internet from my mobile hotspot) and my desktop (Which is using internet from same mobile USB tethering)? Can we do a LAN? I need to share files between them. is there a way to do this connection without using ethernet cable ?

Laptop is running windows10Pro, desktop running windows7 and mobile has android on it.

Laptop IP  : 192.168.43.XXX
Desktop IP : 192.168.42.XXX

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you running on the laptop? On the phone? On the desktop?

Comment: Without knowing the OSes involved, you can create an AdHoc WiFi network on one then have the other connect to it; BT would also be an option, albeit at slower throughput.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a LAN. A LAN is a local network, it does not imply a need for a network cable. You likely just need to enable file sharing.

Comment: @user1686 : My Laptop is running Windows10(64bit), Phone is android(8.0.0) and desktop windows7(64bit)

Answer (score 0):

In theory this would be possible easily: the phone already acts like a router, and it *could* allow the two subnets (USB tethering and Wi-Fi hotspot) to talk to each other; it could even bridge the two into a single subnet if it wanted.

Unfortunately, it seems that Android *deliberately* makes this impossible by blocking all packets going between the two subnets.

Comment: You could add `iptables` rules allowing such traffic, but the Android device must be rooted to do so.